# webRTC connection working when connecting to webpage hosted locally, but not when hosted on a server

Tags: express, socket.io, webrtc, aiortc

I am attempting to create a webRTC connection from a python app to a web service using aiortc on python side, and express js on the web service side. When hosting the web service on localhost I have no problems, however when I host it on a server I am unable. I can still access the web page just fine when hosted online, I just get the following very generic exception when I attempt to make a webRTC connection:
`socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by the server`.

Here is what I think is the relevant part of the python code:

```
import asyncio
import dataclasses
import os
import socketio


from pathlib import Path
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription
from data_streams.StreamingTrack import StreamingTrack

# Socket.io details
NODEJS_URL = 'something.something.nl'
NODEJS_PORT = '4000'
ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
CLASSROOM_ID = "defaultClassroom"

    sio = socketio.AsyncClient()

    await sio.connect("http://" + NODEJS_URL + ":" + NODEJS_PORT)
```

And here is what I believe is the relevant js code:

```
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();
app.options('*', cors());
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));



// initiating the socket server
const port = 4000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.sockets.on('error', (e) => console.log(e));
io.sockets.on('connect_error', (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

If any additional code is needed I can provide it.

The firewalls have been disabled so I don't think that is the issue, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to why I am unable to connect.

Comment: There can be many reasons. first, maybe the port is not open or the port has been used in another service. it's best to check it first

Comment: @kyty how would I go about doing that? I am very new to working with webrtc or anything similar so sorry if this is a dumb question. Also, since I am still able to host the webpage when using the server, wouldn't that mean that the port is open/available?

Comment: Did you run socketIo and Node js app in same port ? if yes ? try to use different port like let's say sockerIo server with port 4000 and app with port 3000